# Asterisk - Cleaning up MySQL() Connections in 'h' Extension

Tags: mysql, asterisk

In one of our very simple custom contexts I would like to add some database logging outside of the built-in cdr app. I have something like the following:

```
[inbound-custom]
exten => _X.,1,MixMonitor(/mnt/temp/inbound-${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}-${CALLERID(num)}-${EXTEN}-${UNIQUEID}.wav)
exten => _X.,n,MYSQL(Connect connid mysqlip cdr_logger mysqlpw asteriskcdrdb)
exten => _X.,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} INSERT INTO `call_recordings` (`asterisk_uniqueid`,`clid`,`filename`,`context`) VALUES (${UNIQUEID},${CALLERID(num)},inbound-${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}-${CALLERID(num)}-${EXTEN}-${UNIQUEID}.wav,"inbound"))
exten => _X.,n,MYSQL(Clear ${resultid}) 
exten => _X.,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid}) 
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/cs1000/${EXTEN})
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

This seems to work fine for the most part, however if someone hangs up before the context reaches the `MYSQL(clear...)` line there is a zombie connection left open on the MySQL server. On the voip info wiki there is mention of doing connection clean up in the `h` extension for a context, but there are no samples of this. I tried the following to no avail:

```
[inbound-custom]
exten => _X.,1,MixMonitor(/mnt/temp/inbound-${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}-${CALLERID(num)}-${EXTEN}-${UNIQUEID}.wav)
exten => _X.,n,MYSQL(Connect connid mysqlip cdr_logger mysqlpw asteriskcdrdb)
exten => _X.,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} INSERT INTO `call_recordings` (`asterisk_uniqueid`,`clid`,`filename`,`context`) VALUES (${UNIQUEID},${CALLERID(num)},inbound-${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}-${CALLERID(num)}-${EXTEN}-${UNIQUEID}.wav,"inbound"))
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/cs1000/${EXTEN})
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()

exten => h,1,MYSQL(Clear ${resultid}) 
exten => h,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid})
```

I imagine I'm doing something wrong in there but I cant quite tell what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this mostly working however clear seems to love throwing errors on inserts and the documentation is minimal at best. Gave up on using `MYSQL()` and opted to use `system()` to send the insert statement to a waiting python daemon.

Comment: That is very bad method. It will result core hangs under load. Correct method - use asterisk cdr_mysql module and triggers/external script. Instead of func_mysql have be used func_odbc or function REALTIME.